# Why do comments by myself and others on my news feed not appear on my Facebook timeline when I share the post?

Tags: facebook-timeline

When I share someone's post on my own timeline, why do the accompanying comments by myself and others not appear with it?

Answer (score 1):

You are sharing the post, by that action you are creating a new post with a new slate for users to write comments.

If you were using a website, you can embed the post instead.